# Accessing information stored in a database on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku

I am working on an open source application for running soundcloud remix competitions. My app is running here, http://plpcomp11.herokuapp.com/

It has a voting system which automatically shows the top three entries, but only the top three and doesn't display the number of votes for each entry.

I want to access from the database, how many votes have been cast for each entry. Any ideas how to do this???

The database files are here on github.

https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-remix/tree/master/db

Answer (score 0):

You mean, something like this?

in controller:

```
@remixes = Remix.all(:order => 'votes_count DESC', :limit => 3)
```

in view:

```
@remixes.each do |remix|
  "#{remix.track_id} has #{remix.votes_count} votes"
end
```

Comment: Hi thankyou for your response. I have 6 Controller files and 6 veiw folders. Sorry but no idea which ones to put your code into.

Comment: Ok. So, I assume, you have a `app/controllers/remixes_controller.rb` controller and `app/views/remixes/show.html.erb` view.
Put `@remixes = Remix.all(:order => 'votes_count DESC', :limit => 3)` in that controller and `<% @remixes.each do |remix| %>
  <p><%= remix.track_id %> has <%= remix.votes_count %> votes</p>
<% end %>` in view.

Comment: I have a app/controllers/tracks_controller.rb and app controllers/tracks/show.html.haml Doews this mean I should change remixes to tracks in your code?

Comment: You can rename it as you wish, but if you store there a records from `Remix` model, it's quite obvious to name it `@remixes` or `@top_remixes`. Just for clarity.